# How to connect a java program to Derby in netbeans 7.2.1

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

im a novice programmer and i wanna know what is the basic way to connect a java program to Derby in netbeans 7.2.1. my prof asked me to make a program that lets me add, delete, save, search and edit entries from a table. i already know how to make a GUI java program in netbeans and how to make a database on netbeans too. i just want to know what are the basic codes to include in a program to enable it to connect on a database on netbeans 7.2.1. thank you for your time reading my question.

`public void connection(){
    try{
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            String myDb = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HWtrial";
            Connection DBconn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDb, "","");
            s1 = DBconn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            result = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * from HWSTUD");
            result.next();

            result.last();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cannot Connect to Database", "Error Message", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
          };
}`

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: i've updated my question. the code is above. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Derby documentation contains an excellent set of tutorials to help you get started: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/

Answer (score 0):

```
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        String myDb = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HWtrial";
        Connection DBconn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDb, "","");
         Statement st=DBconn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student");
         while(rs.next)
          {
            out.println(rs.getString(1));
          }|
```